# referring to sum of elements in column with Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

My employee's IT department refuses to install R for me (claiming the open source version is a security risk) and I tried to create reports with Microsoft Access 2010.

I got stuck trying to create a query on a simple table of hospital wards (for the purpose of keeping track of a data collection exercise):

[image: example table]

I did not manage to allocate each ward a sample size that would be proportional to its bed capacity (third column above) as I was not able to refer to the sum of the elements in the "bedCapacity" column. With Excel, I would try something like this:

[image: Excel table]

Cell D2 in Excel contains `=INT(C2/SUM(C$2:C$6)*50)+1` and cells D3 to D6 according formulae.

Is there any way I can refer to the sum in the `bedCapacity` column in Access 2010? I tried creating a separate query that would sum up the the 'bedCapacity` column, however could not figure out how to refer to the value in that query.

I'm trying to use Access 2010 so I can create standardised reports for the data collectors on their progress (which is not easily possible with Excel 2010, as it requires too much manual manipulation - I tried pivot tables etc.).

Would be grateful for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and save this query to give you the total bed capacity from all wards.

```sql
SELECT Sum(bedCapacity) AS TotalBeds
FROM YourTable;
```

Replace *YourTable* with the name of your table, of course.  For the rest of this answer, I will pretend you saved that query with the name *qryGrandTotalBedCapacity*.

Then you can use that query in another where you [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) it with your table.  The cross join gives you a result set which pairs each row of one data source with every row of the other data source.

However, since *qryGrandTotalBedCapacity* returns only a single row, this amounts to just making the `TotalBeds` value available for every row of *YourTable*.  And, from that starting point, it is easy to translate your Excel formula to the Access SQL equivalent.

```sql
SELECT
    y.ID,
    y.ward,
    y.bedCapacity,
    (INT((y.bedCapacity/q.TotalBeds) * 50) + 1) AS sampleSize
FROM YourTable AS y, qryGrandTotalBedCapacity AS q;
```

Answer (score 0):

My *RoundSum* function will do that:

```vb
Public Sub ListSampleSizes(ByVal BedCapacity As Variant, ByVal SampleSum As Long)

    Dim SampleSizes As Variant
    Dim Item        As Long
    
    SampleSizes = RoundSum(BedCapacity, SampleSum)
    For Item = LBound(SampleSizes) To UBound(SampleSizes)
        Debug.Print Item + 1, BedCapacity(Item), SampleSizes(Item)
    Next
           
End Sub
```

Result:

```
 1             22            12 
 2             18            10 
 3             20            11 
 4             16            9 
 5             19            11
```

Too much code to post here, but full code is for download at **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my query. I would prefer a solution without VBA (so I can more easily distribute the file among colleagues) and will go with the answer of HansUp.